# Passing Parameter to a TextBox

Tags: c#, parameters, textbox

I am am trying to pass a parameter into my textbox which communicates to my database and runs a stored procedure on a button click.

I have the button working if I hard code a parameter value but I need to to accept parameters in a textbox.

Any ideas how I can fix this code to accomplish this?

This is one of my classes

```
public FixPayrollMonth PayrollMonth()
{
    return StoreProcPayrollMonth("fix_Payroll_PayingMonth");
}

private FixPayrollMonth StoreProcPayrollMonth(string storeprocedurename)
{
    FixPayrollMonth result = new FixPayrollMonth() {IsSuccess = false };
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storeprocedurename, Connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Month_Change", 123456 ));         
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    using (var data = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (data.Read())
        {
            result.MonthChanged = Convert.ToInt32(data["MonthChanged"]);
            result.IsSuccess = Convert.ToBoolean(data["IsSuccess"]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is my button click...I need to link it to my textbox called txtPay

```
protected void btnFixMnth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = repo.PayrollMonth();
    if (result.IsSuccess)
    {
        lblMessageBoxMnthChg.Text = "Succesful Month has been changed to: " + result.MonthChanged;
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessageBoxMnthChg.Text = "Failed to change month";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a parameter into my textbox"?  Do you just want to set it's value?  `txtPay.Text = "some value"` would accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to repo.PayrollMonth would required a parameter to pass in the value of the textbox.  So in your button click event you would do:

```
 var result = repo.PayrollMonth(txtPay.Text);
```

And you repo would need to be modified to look like the following:

```
 public FixPayrollMonth(string pay)
 {
      StoreProcPayrollMonth("fix_Payroll_PayingMonth", pay);
}

private FixPayrollMonth StoreProcPayrollMonth(string storeprocedurename, string pay)
{
    FixPayrollMonth result = new FixPayrollMonth() {IsSuccess = false };
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storeprocedurename, Connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Month_Change", pay ));         
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection.Open();



    using (var data = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (data.Read())
        {
            result.MonthChanged = Convert.ToInt32(data["MonthChanged"]);
            result.IsSuccess = Convert.ToBoolean(data["IsSuccess"]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```